# Access Child Item's individual ojects in Expandable Listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How do I access the child views of child items in any group view in expandable listview??

```
selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int gourpsSum = adapter.getGroupCount();  
             for(int i = 0; i < gourpsSum; i++) {  
                 int childSum = adapter.getChildrenCount(i);
                 for(int k = 0; k < childSum;k++) {  
                     boolean isLast = false;  
                     if (k == (childSum - 1)){   
                         isLast = true;  
                     }  

                     CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) adapter.getChildView(i, k, isLast, null, null).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);  
                     cBox.setChecked(selectAll.isChecked());
                     ((BaseExpandableListAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                 }  

             }  
        }  
});
```

where selectAll is another Checkbox above the expandable listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a class to extend the [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html), and then override the abstract [getChildView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildView(int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method, this method is based on groupPosition and childPosition to determine which view to be displayed. You can also visit this [Expandable List View tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).

In the tutorial, it shows how to access the TextView object in each child view, if you want to access the CheckBox, you can do the similar thing. Below is a sample code:

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        CheckBox checkboxListChild = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkboxListItem); //assume thats the id of your checkbox object


        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }
```

You can also check out [this tutorial](http://blog.csdn.net/lfdfhl/article/details/10532859) to learn about ExpandableListView with checkbox.

Comment: that I know but my question is that suppose I have an expandable listview in which each childview consists of a checkbox and a textview. Now how can I access the checkbox object when the list is either expanded or collapsed??

Comment: Thnx...I still have a problem. Like I have a select all checkbox above the list.When select all is checked all checkbox's state should change accordingly.Now with the help of link I'm able to change the state of the checkboxes but it is not reflected in the list.Can u explain why??