# How to access items inside ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView. When I click on one of these lists, I have several items.

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/311437expandablelistview.png

Is there a way or not to access to the first item in the first group ?
I have

```
private ExpandableListView mGattServicesList;

SimpleExpandableListAdapter gattServiceAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(...);

mGattServicesList.setAdapter(gattServiceAdapter);
```

I can access to the first group with :

```
mGattServicesList.getChildAt(0);
```

I want to go now inside this child to get items but I can't find a way.

Alright here is the function where I want to do this :

```
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    if (gattServices == null) return;

    String uuid = null;
    String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
    String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
            = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
        currentServiceData.put(
                LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
        currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
        gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattService.getCharacteristics();

        ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

        // Loops through available Characteristics.
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
            charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
            HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
            currentCharaData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
            currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
            gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
        }
        mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
        gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
    }

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter gattServiceAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,gattServiceData,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            gattCharacteristicData, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
    );
    mGattServicesList.setAdapter(gattServiceAdapter);
    mGattServicesList.performItemClick(mGattServicesList.getChildAt(1), 1, mGattServicesList.getItemIdAtPosition(1));

}
```

The perform click is to get the group1 extanded, then I want to do a perform click to the 2nd item inside.

Thank you in advance

Comment: look to this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914488/access-child-items-individual-ojects-in-expandable-listview still if you have issue let me know

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is my class is already extending Activity so I can't implement the method getChildView()..

Answer (score 0):

First please post the adapter you are using
second getchild function should get groupPosition and childPosition.
it seems like you use regular list adapter instead of expendable one.

**Edit:**

I see you try to get the item via the list instead from the Adapter I believe this will solve your problem.

Also i am stronglly reccomend you to make custom adapter instead of use the basic one just in case you want any change

Comment: Can you detail please ?

Comment: to populate the list you need to use an adapter right? then it would be helpful if you post the adapter you are using

Comment: almost i need the 3 dots in there SimpleExpandableListAdapter(...); also this guide might help you http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/android-simple-expandable-listview.html

Comment: @Bob havae you seen the Edit you need to get item from adapter and not from the List Object

Comment: I srly don't understand what you mean. I can only access to the adapter with the list so I have to use it. for example mGattServicesList.getExpandableListAdapter()

Comment: i mean use gattServiceAdapter to get the child.you can put this object as class parmeter if you need it in some places

Comment: Ok using gattServiceAdapter I can access to the child. I want now to perform a click on it so I have something like : gattServiceAdapter.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition,isLastChild,convertView, parent).performClick() . I want group 1 and child 2, and it's not the lastchild. What will be the convertView and the parent parameters ?

Comment: We use get child view to build as in ListAdapter. can you please write what are you trying to achive?

Comment: As you can see in the picture ( in the question ), I have an expandablelist with 3 groups with items inside. What I'd like to do is to make a click with performClick() method to an item inside a group. In my case, I'd like to do it on 2nd item of 1st group. I don't know if that's clear, let me know if it isn't.Maybe what I want to do is impossible.. I don't know..

Comment: i am trying to get why are you trying to performclick if u want to run function just run it with the position also you can store tag on the view with the postions when overriding getchildview in your customadapter

Comment: Can you provide me the two last parameters of getChildView method knowing convertView and parent ? please..