# How to select child in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I already asked the question but with no success. So I'm asking again (sorry btw).

I still have this issue :

[How to access items inside ExpandableListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011806/how-to-access-items-inside-expandablelistview).

Let me resume. I have this situation in my app :

[image]

I want to make a performClick() on the 2dn item of the 2nd group.
All I can do for the moment is to expand the second group with a performClick() using this line of code :

```
 mGattServicesList.performItemClick(mGattServicesList.getChildAt(1), 1, mGattServicesList.getItemIdAtPosition(1));
```

knowing

```
private ExpandableListView mGattServicesList;
```

Isn't there a very simple way to performClick() to the item inside a group ?

I want to do it because I have then a listner like

```
private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
        new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                        int childPosition, long id) {
```

But I don't want to click to the item by myself and I don't find a way to select this specific item in this group.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, the `ExpandableListView` supports an easy way to expand the group you need:

```
mGattServicesList.expandGroup(groupPosition);
```

To programmatically click an item is a little tricky. You're on the right track with using the `performItemClick()` method but you are a little off on how to use it. I will assume you are not using headers. That further complicates things.

First you need to obtain the View to be clicked. Oddly enough, this is not a requirement. You can safely invoke `performItemClick()` with a null View. The only downside being is that your child click listener will also receive a null view.

```
//First we need to pack the child's two position identifiers
long packedPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition);

//Then we convert to a flat position to use with certain ListView methods
int flatPos = mGattServicesList.getFlatListPosition(packedPos);

//Now adjust the position based on how far the user has scrolled the list.
int adjustedPos = flatPos - mGattServicesList.getFirstVisiblePosition();

//If all is well, the adjustedPos should never be < 0
View childToClick = mGattServicesList.getChildAt(adjustedPos);
```

Now we need the position and id to feed to `performItemclick()`. You'll see the steps are similar to retrieving the View. So really, you don't have to further type this out again...but to show what you need:

```
//You can just reuse the same variables used above to find the View
long packedPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition);
int flatPos = mGattServicesList.getFlatListPosition(packedPos);

//Getting the ID for our child
long id = mGattServicesList.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition);
```

Finally, you can invoke your `performItemClick()`:

```
performItemClick(childToClick, flatPos, id);
```

I should preface, I didn't get to check this code against an IDE so there may be some syntax errors that'll prevent compilation. But all in all should convey the, unfortunately, not so easy steps in programmatically clicking a child view.

Final note, the pic you provided shows the group and child counts start at 1. Be aware that they are actually considered zero based positions. So the first group is at position 0 and the first child for each group is at position 0.

Comment: Thanks for this reply! however it seems that getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition) method doesn't exist and I can't find an other method in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#getSelectedId%28%29

Comment: Yes , that worked !! Indeed , in the line mGattServicesList.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition); I changed it into : mGattServicesList.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildId(1,2); and worked perfectly well, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Updated my answer to fix the mistake.

Comment: I tried this solution, in the backend all variables look good, but the UI is not refreshed, the selection is not moved to the right item (not moved at all). Do you have any suggestion to refresh the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a listener for a specific item in a list, but you can do what you want. Just check to see if `groupPosition` and `childPosition` are the ones you want, then do the action (or some other action appropriate to the other items)

In the `ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener`

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    //groupPosition tells you what group the clicked child came from
    //childPosition tells you what child was clicked
    if (groupPosition == 2 && childPosition == 2) {
        //so this code only executes if the 2nd child in the 2nd group is clicked 
    }
    //you can ignore the other items or do something else when they are clicked
}
```

Comment: Ok but with this solution, I will still have to click to the child by myself right ?

Comment: Yeah.. I wanted to performClick() in an other function so that it actually calls onChildClick()

Comment: Ah, my misunderstanding. I have an idea. Give me a second.