# How to programatically perform ExpandableListView child item click

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have one ExpandableListView in my view. I have implemented its child click listener and it's working perfectly.

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
}
```

Now, i also want programatically perform child click. Is it possible to call it programmatically?

I have tried by returning my `convertView` on `getChild()` method and performing on click on that by,

```
((View)updateListAdapter.getChild(0, 2)).performClick();
```

but with no luck. It's not calling `onChildClick()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandableListView` does have a method

```
public boolean performItemClick (View v, int position, long id)
```

but there is just one position argument; where's the group/child?

I looked at the code, and what it wants is a *flat* position.  So something like this should work (sorry I haven't tried it):

```
long packedPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForChild(group, child);
int flatPosition = expListView.getFlatListPosition(packedPosition);
expListView.performItemClick(view, flatPosition, childId);
```

Comment: what is view here? performItemClick(view -> this )

Comment: @AlpAltunel It's the view of the item you want to click.  I left that step out, but obviously you need the view to make this work.  This answer explains it better than I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28335106/4504191

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible, all you need to get `ChildView` from `ExpandableListView` then `performClick()`, like:

```
expandableList.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildView(1, 0, true, null, null).performClick();
```

It works well...

once ChildView is in your pocket then you can also access & play with its sub-views, like:

```
(expandableList.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildView(1, 0, true, null, null).findViewById(R.id.btn_continue)).performClick();
```

hope it will help you